# Windows 2008 RC2 IIS6 SMTP Virtual Servers - Limited to 4

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, smtp, iis-6

In line with this post: http://www.hugheserblog.com/2012/05/22/error-creating-iis-smtp-virtual-servers/ I am receiving the same issues:

> When we tried to add more than 4 IIS SMTP virtual servers, we got the error within IIS, “The system cannot find the path specified.”

This post is almost 2 years old and my server is up to date with Windows updates so I assumed it would be fixed already.

Does anyone know if I need to do something special (ie. contact Microsoft) to get a special fix for this? The information in the post suggests it should have been included in an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the following hotfix : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2672620 and see if it helps.